# Making a simple Calculator, but it only knows addition

Tags: vb.net, winforms

My Problem is every time i try to code the subtraction like `TextBox1.Text = firstValue - secondValue` in my equal button the addition button also become subtract so how can i fix this ?

```vb
Dim firstValue, secondValue As Int32

Private Sub Button15_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button15.Click
    secondValue = TextBox1.Text
    TextBox1.Text = firstValue + secondValue
    (here's the equal button)
End Sub

Private Sub Button16_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button16.Click
    TextBox1.Clear()
End Sub

Private Sub Button11_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button11.Click
    firstValue = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text)
    TextBox1.Clear()
    (here's the Addition Button )
End Sub

Private Sub Button12_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button12.Click
    (Here's the button of the Subtraction )
End Sub
```

Comment: Suggestion, give your buttons meaningful names like `AdditionButton`, `SubtractionButton`, `EqualsButton`. Then only create the methods. They will automatically have names like `SubtractionButton_Click`.

Comment: In addition to `firstValue` and `secondValue`, you need a variable for `operation`. When someone clicks the button, set that the variable. When someone clicks the equal button, do a `Select` on the operation to know how to calculate the result.

Answer (score 0):

This is approximating Windows' calculator's basic functionality, but there's a lot more work to do to get its full functionality. For a simple calculator, it's good enough

```vb
Private firstOperand As Double
Private func As Func(Of Double, Double, Double)
Private Sub DivideButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DivideButton.Click
    If Double.TryParse(OperandTextBox.Text, firstOperand) Then
        func = Function(a, b) a / b
        ExpressionLabel.Text = $"{firstOperand} /"
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub MultiplyButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MultiplyButton.Click
    If Double.TryParse(OperandTextBox.Text, firstOperand) Then
        func = Function(a, b) a * b
        ExpressionLabel.Text = $"{firstOperand} x"
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub SubtractButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SubtractButton.Click
    If Double.TryParse(OperandTextBox.Text, firstOperand) Then
        func = Function(a, b) a - b
        ExpressionLabel.Text = $"{firstOperand} -"
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub AddButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AddButton.Click
    If Double.TryParse(OperandTextBox.Text, firstOperand) Then
        func = Function(a, b) a + b
        ExpressionLabel.Text = $"{firstOperand} +"
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub EqualsButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles EqualsButton.Click
    Dim secondOperand As Double
    If Double.TryParse(OperandTextBox.Text, secondOperand) Then
        ExpressionLabel.Text &= $" {secondOperand}"
        OperandTextBox.Text = $"{func(firstOperand, secondOperand)}"
    End If
End Sub
```

You will need to add the controls. Using nice names always helps because nobody wants to guess what `Button11` does when it can be called `AddButton`.

Store the operation in a function when you click the button, then invoke the function later when equals is pressed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution allowing continuous calculations:

```vb
Private Enum Operation
    None
    Add
    Subtract
End Enum

Dim accumulator As Integer
Dim op As Operation

Private Sub AdditionButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles additionButton.Click
    Execute()
    op = Operation.Add
End Sub

Private Sub SubtractionButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles subtractionButton.Click
    Execute()
    op = Operation.Subtract
End Sub

Private Sub ClearButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles clearButton.Click
    op = Operation.None
    accumulator = 0
    resultTextBox.Text = "0"
End Sub

Private Sub EqualsButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles equalsButton.Click
    Execute()
    op = Operation.None
End Sub

Private Sub Execute()
    Select Case op
        Case Operation.None
            If IsNumeric(inputTextBox.Text) Then
                accumulator = CInt(inputTextBox.Text)
            End If
        Case Operation.Add
            Dim secondValue As Integer = CInt(inputTextBox.Text)
            accumulator += secondValue
        Case Operation.Subtract
            Dim secondValue As Integer = CInt(inputTextBox.Text)
            accumulator -= secondValue
    End Select
    resultTextBox.Text = accumulator.ToString()
    inputTextBox.Text = ""
    inputTextBox.Select()
End Sub
```

I use an `Enum` to remember the operation that will be performed when clicking the equal button. Instead of clicking equal, you can also click + or - again and enter a new number. Only after the last number has been entered, you must click the equals button.

The clear button is not strictly required but is nice to have.

Note that I have two textboxes. One for input and one to display results. The result textbox has `Enabled = False` and `BackColor = White`. I also selected a larger font for it.